# TimePicker Dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm using multiple textviews with onclick listeners that direct me to a TimePicker Dialog.

However I cannot seem to know how to write the code after reading the tutorials,

```
    textview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    textview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
```

To show the dialog:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, true);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and finally,

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view,
                    int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mHour = hourOfDay;
                mMinute = minute;
            }
        };
```

now, to .setText for the textview that CALLED the timepicker after the TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener  callback, how should I write the code?

The answer is very simple but I lack OOP knowledge and still learning.
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a global varible. say,`String fromWhere="";`

now,

```
    textview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fromWhere="textview1";
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
    });

    textview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fromWhere="textview2";
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
    });
    ...
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view,
                        int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    if(fromWhere.equals(textview1))
                           // set hour and minute to according variable and textview
                    else if(fromWhere.equals(textview2))
                           // set hour and minute to according variable and textview
                    .. //so on for others
                    //mHour = hourOfDay;
                    //mMinute = minute;
                    fromWhere="";
                }
    };
```

Comment: how to show dialoge in what if I am in adapter, I mean class inherit from ArrayAdapter<Class> , I cannot say showdialoge(0);

Comment: @AHM: why do you need to open dialog from Adapter class? you can do that in activity itself,by getting relevant id of the list item(if you are using ArrayAdapter to render list).

Answer (score 1):

create a member variable (say `int whichViewClicked = 0`) in your class to keep track of the textview clicked to bring-up the time-picker.

Now if you click textview1 set whichViewClicked = 1, if textview2 is clicked set whichViewClicked = 2 and so on. In the onTimeSet() method check the value of whichViewClicked and set the textview text accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use EditText and we can get time pikker long press on edit text.

```
EditText timeDisplay=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);

timeDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) {

        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);    
    }    
});
```