# show TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have editbox I want when click on it to show TimePickerDialog instead of the keyboard , and when select the time the picker disappear and the time be shown in the edittext

this EditText is adaptor class like this

```
public class TminuseistAdaptar  extends ArrayAdapter<Tr> {

    private final Context context;
    ArrayList<Tr> TrBasics ; 

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    CheckBox Confirm ; 
    ImageButton DialUp;

     EditText data ; 

    public TminuseistAdaptar(Context context, int  ResourceId,
            ArrayList<Tr> items)
    {


        super(context, ResourceId, items);
         this.context = context;
         this.TrBasics = items ; 

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

}
}
```

I did something like that for the editText

```
textViewEncounterType = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TminuseTime);
        textViewEncounterType.setText(TreatementMinuseObject.TBasic.TreatementTime);
        textViewEncounterType.setTag(position);



        textViewEncounterType.setClickable(true);
        textViewEncounterType.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        textViewEncounterType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new TimePickerDialog(context, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, false);

            }
        });
```

but nothing appear , I call this adapter class in another class extend Fragement

```
public class TminusList   extends Fragment {
```

Best regards

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383550/timepicker-dialog

Comment: take a look at these links http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/, http://androidexam.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-time-picker-dialog-example.html, http://thesarmad.blogspot.in/2009/12/time-picker-example-android.html

Comment: what if I am in adapter, I mean class inherit from ArrayAdapter<Class>

Comment: You've gotten two answers that answer the question you asked and you say won't work.  Fix your question to ask for what you really need.  Preferably add your current code so we can understand what is going on at the point you want the timepicker.

Comment: I already did see my update question

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this (for a fragment implementation):

```
startTxt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.joindate);
startTxt.setClickable(true);
startTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

startTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimeDialog();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
});
```

And TimeDialog:

```
public class TimeDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Set your view
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, false);      }
}
```

This code will cause the EditText box to pop the timepicker dialog instead of the keyboard (once you put in the timepicker dialog code).

Note you need to set the EditText (in the example above it would be the EditText with the `joindate` id) with `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in your XML or it will take two clicks to get the dialog to open.

Comment: how to show dialoge in what if I am in adapter, I mean class inherit from ArrayAdapter<Class> , I cannot say showdialoge(0);

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem, I'm afraid not.  See the line `startTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`?  That means no keyboard.  I use this exact code in one of my apps, and it pops my dateslider dialog without any hint of the keyboard appearing.

Comment: +1 for `startTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` as I have not seen it:)

Comment: could u see my updated question I added al u said but not dialoge appear

Comment: If you are using fragments, and calling that adapter from your fragment, then `context` is the context of the fragment (as you've coded it), not the activity.  A dialog needs an activity context.  Change `context` to `getActivity()` and it should work. You really should create a DialogFragment and use that though.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
startTxt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //show DateTimepicker
                return true; //very important in your case if you return false keayboard will open
            }
        });
```

Comment: the problem is in how to show dialoge in what if I am in adapter, I mean class inherit from ArrayAdapter<Class> , I cannot say showdialoge(0);

Comment: you can use `new DatePickerDialog(context,
        datePickerListener, 2012, 10, 10).show();` I think you are passing the context here..
      `

Comment: could u see my updated question I added al u said but not dialoge appear